# How to calculate $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Any idea about this problem:

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}=1$$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Logs with complex numbers are tricky: which branch did you choose for it?

Comment: @Avitus $\mathbb{C}^-=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{z\in \mathbb{R}:z\le 0\}$

Comment: @StefanHansen Even though the question is pretty much the same, this on is tagged with complex analysis and the other is tagged with calculus and limits. Even though this works here it is not immeadetely clear, why the existence of the limit in the restriction on $\mathbb{R}$ gives the existence of the limit in $\mathbb{C}$. In many cases this is just wrong

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Point taken, I did not take notice of the tag. I was merely focusing on the $\lim_{z\to 0}$ which suggested that $z$   is a real parameter. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}=\frac{\log(1+z)-\log(1)}{(z+1)-1}$$
So the limit is equal to $\log'(1)=1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You can use that the Laurent expansion of the numerator is
$$
\log(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{z^n}{n} \qquad\qquad \text{for $|z|<1$}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use l'Hopital rule,

$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{(\log(1+z))'}{(z)'}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1}{1+z}=1
$$
For complex functions, L'Hopital rule does not work in general but works in special cases. Because your functions are analytic at 0, the rule works here.

Comment: Sorry but why should it work? In the proof of L'hopital you use cauchy's mean value theorem which is cleary wrong in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, this post explains it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194722/lhopital-rule-on-mathbbc

Comment: Oh you mean that. For me this is more Taylor then L'hopital but ok.

Comment: Indeed you just have  to extend the concept of differentiability and analyticity to complex functions. And yes, you can use Taylor to derive l'Hopital, I think.

Comment: as I am pretty confident that Taylor is much stronger than L'hopital this should work without problems

Answer (score 0):

If I right, there is a l'Hôpital's rule for a complex function, and hence
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1+z}}{1}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think if it is in the reals,

Use z = 1/n , and consider what happens when n----> infinity.

:Log(1+z)/z would become log (1+ [1/n])^n .

It is easy to see that the latter expression tends to log e =1, because as n ----> infinity , (1+[1/n])^n -----> e.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for mathematical equations.